# AWS and C# Serverless Application - can't find context to access ID token

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless

Our company just started working with AWS and I have been tasked with creatiing Lambda functions for the API Gateway.  I have c# background so that is the language I decided to use.  When determining which "blueprint" to use, it seemed the "AWS Serverless Application with Tests" was the right blueprint since I would be making multiple functions. The first function will be to create an application user.  The user must be created in the database User table and also in Cognito.

Based on my searches for help with my issue, most applications seem to be written in a manner that allows users to sign themselves up.  Ours is not the case.  An Administrator must create a user.  We are using Cognito to authenticate both the administrators and the application users so each user, irrespective of type, must be created in the database User table and in Cognito.

The problem I have is that, when a user logs in and is authenticated via Cognito and causes a Lambda function to execute, I need to access the ID Token to get the user's Cognito credentials so I can look them up in the User table.  When I search for how to do that, virtually all the help that I find refers to a context object found in the Function.cs file.  But the Serverless Application doesn't have a function.cs file. The Serverless Application has the following files:
- LambdaEntryPoint.cs
- Startup.cs
- NameOfYourChoiceController.cs

None of those files (classes) have access to a context object. All of last week, I had access to a consultant who is experienced in AWS but not in .NET.  We never were able to determine how to access the ID token.  I'm hoping somebody here can help.

TIA,
Dar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HttpContext.User** is what you are looking for to get Cognito information

Its added at 2.0. [Changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/RELEASE.CHANGELOG.md)

> - Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer (2.0.0)
>
>   - If Cognito claims are found on
>       an incoming API Gateway request create a ClaimsPrincipal with the
>       claims for the HttpContext.User.

You also have a look at the [source code](http://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/APIGatewayProxyFunction.cs)

It took me a while to figure that out also ;)

An example usage

```
[HttpGet]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var x = HttpContext.User;
    var y = x?.Claims;
    LambdaLogger.Log(y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful.  I haven't been able to  validate that I can get what I'm looking for yet because I can't figure out how to generate a SessionToken for a Cognito user.  I tried to generate one using aws cli but so far, as near as i can tell, I've only been able to generate tokens for a federated id but I need one for a specific user in a user pool.  I can get tokens for a federated identity but we aren't using federated identities. Maybe we have a misunderstanding of how user pools and federated Identities work?  Your tip was useful, I just haven't been able to test it.

Comment: You are trying to get the user info right? Like IDToken, Sub, Username etc... Those should be included in HttpContext.User. Of course, assuming that ApiGateway has Cognito Authorizer set. I wasn't mentioning about federated identities and wasn't using it. Neither does you as you say.

Comment: What I need is a custom attribute value.  It contains the value of a record id in our database. I should add that I am using either Postman or the API Gateway to test my Lambda functions.  That's why I was trying to generate a session token for a Cognito user.

Comment: I'm back to this one now.  I was able to get credentials for one of our User Pool users.  I plugged them into Postman and successfully execute a POST on the API.  However, when I checked the log, where I wrote out some debug information, it shows the following:

HttpContext.User.Claims.Count =  0

Comment: I can personally verify that it works and I am using it in production environment now. It also logs to the console as you can see if you examine the source I posted as a link. Are you using AspNetCoreServer 2.0.0 surely ? If so try logging Request.HttpContext.Items['APIGatewayRequest'] objects. It has APIGatewayRequest inside and you will be able to see if cognito claims are actually inside

Comment: I believe it is working for you.  It just isn't working for me.  The APIGatewayRequest object has  a value in RequestContext.Identity.CognitoIdentityId as well as in .RequestContext.Identity.CognitoIdentityPoolId.
The requestUser contains "<identifier>:CognitoIdentityCredentials"

Comment: The RequestContext.Identity.Caller contains "<identifier>:CognitoIdentityCredentials" But there is nothing in user.Claims.

Comment: Am I missing something in LambdaEntryPoint, StartUp or serverless.template?

Comment: I dont know. It can be anything. I cant tell more at this point. I am using serverless framework by the way. If you wanna put your repository into github (by deleting credentials etc) I can have a look at it.

Comment: I so very much appreciate your assistance.  I put the code here: https://github.com/dhsass/TCServerlessApp

Comment: Ok let me know when you commit your code to the repo. Its currently empty

Comment: Sorry about that.  I forgot to push it.  It is there now.

Comment: yeah i posted an issue. These comments are not really user friendly for communicating ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see if I can figure that out.

Comment: I created a case with Amazon last week.  This is how they started their response.  "The HttpContext.User does not offer user details directly at the Lambda end. The user details are present in the context object of API Gateway that needs to be passed onto the Lambda function’s event object through body mapping templates." Does this correlate with your experience because it seems to contradict my understanding of what you have been telling me?

Comment: Yes I know the mappings but they are applied already in 'lamda proxy' integration. There is check box called 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' in Integration Request section of the proxy resource at apigateway console. I remember reading something regarding to it. Plus I never did a custom mapping.